# Discord.py not responding to button events

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

Here's a test command in my bot.

```
@tree.command(name="button", description="testing")
async def button(interaction):
    view = discord.ui.View()  # make a view
    style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary  # makes the button blue
    item = discord.ui.Button(style=style, label="Click to continue!", custom_id="continue_button")  # make the button
    view.add_item(item=item)  # add button to view
    await interaction.response.send_message("Waiting until you press the button!", view=view)  # send message with button

    def check(i):
        return i.user.id == interaction.user.id and i.custom_id == "continue_button"

    try:
        interaction, button = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=check, timeout=10)
        # when button is pressed
        await interaction.channel.send("You pressed the button!")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # button wasn't pressed before timeout
        await interaction.channel.send("You didn't press the button within the specified time.")
```

However, the bot never gets the button click event! Even if the check is nothing, no custom ID, etc, the bot times out and click the button results in interaction failed. Also, I'd like to keep the button and listening within the command so that I can execute more code based on the button the user presses.

I expected the bot to send a message that I had clicked the button, but I always get a timeout even after pressing the button. I have tried removing the check, timeout, etc, but I cannot get the event to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because there is not a button_click event. Instead, look for interactions that were caused by buttons:

```py
interaction = await client.wait_for('interaction', 
    check=lambda i:
    i.type == discord.InteractionType.component and
    i.user == interaction.user and
    i.channel == interaction.channel, timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning, but I don't think you are calling the check function/inputting a parameter

Comment: Can you clarify more on what you mean/what to change?

Comment: You are missing the lambda part
For example:
try insted of check=check,
check = lambda check

Comment: so your entire line would be:
interaction, button = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda check, timeout=10)

Comment: if that doesnt work, you instead need to add the view
interaction, button = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=check, timeout=10, view=view)

Comment: No, it doesn't work no matter the check, even if there is none; plus, view isn't a keyword argument for client.wait_for

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `lambda` is. `lambda` is known as a single line function. The post author has made it a separate function. More commonly, `client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author.id == interaction.user.id)`, with `m` being `message`

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue quite recently. The problem is that `"button_click"` event for `client.wait_for` only exists if you're using the `discord-components` library.

It would be a lot better to use a `callback` for what you're doing.

Additionally, you also want a response message on timeout. So it would be best to use a class.

```
class MyButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click to continue!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def mybutton_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You pressed the button!")


@tree.command(name="button", description="testing")
async def button(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Waiting until you press the button!", view=MyButtonView())  # send message with button
```

That is the baseline for a button.

### Verifying user

You want to check that the person who clicks the button is also the one who uses the command.
We can achieve this by making our own `interaction_check` method in the class.

Python explanation: the `MyButtonView` class inherits `discord.ui.View` class, which has the method `interaction_check`. By writing our own, we override this.

In that method, simply check if the author is interaction user. We get the author by parsing an argument, requiring `__init__`.

```
class MyButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author):
        self.author = author

    @discord.ui.button(label="Click to continue!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def mybutton_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You pressed the button!")
    
    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return self.author.id == interaction.user.id
```

Since `MyButtonView` is now expecting the `author` argument we have to parse that in when sending the button message.

```
await interaction.response.send_message("...", view=MyButtonView(interaction.user))
```

### Timeout

Now we want it to send a message when it times out. Again, we make our own method `on_timeout`. However, this doesn't have any arguments, so we have to parse in `interaction` ourselves.

```
class MyButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, interaction):
        self.interaction = interaction

    @discord.ui.button(label="Click to continue!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def mybutton_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You pressed the button!")

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return self.interaction.user.id == interaction.user.id

    async def on_timeout(self): # No interaction argument
        await self.interaction.channel.send("You didn't press the button within the specified time.")
```

This also removes the need for the `author` argument because we can get the same from the `interaction` argument.

Do note the difference between the interaction parsed in as an argument in `__init__`, `self.interaction` and the button `interaction`.

#### Documentation

For more on buttons, [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button), [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction), [discord.ui.View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View),  [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Final note: Sorry such a long answer, wanted to be in depth with this for you to have full understanding of what you're doing.